# Why result does not get shared?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have following code snippet:

```
const source$ = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4])
  .filter(x => x % 2)
  .map(x => x * x)
  .share();

source$.subscribe(x => console.log(`Stream 1 ${x}`));
source$.subscribe(x => console.log(`Stream 2 ${x}`));
```

As the result I've got
[image]

But I am excepting shared results like:

```
"Stream 1 1"
"Stream 2 1"
"Stream 1 9"
"Stream 2 9"
```

Why the result does not get shared?

Comment: RxJS will try to go a synchronous way whenever possible - in this case `Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4])` can be _"done"_ synchronous, that's why you'll see stream1 first - in this case "Stream1" will even complete and "Stream2" will create a new instance of the flow then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're using a cold Observable (http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html).

When you subscribe for the first time it takes the `refCount()` operator and subscribes to its source Observable which is the `Observable.from()`. This all happens synchronously so it emits all its values the the subscriber and then emits complete which makes the `refCount()` unsubscribe from the source because there're no other Observers.

Then you subscribe with the second Observer and this all happens again.

If you wanted to achieve your expected result that you could use just `publish()` to turn the source into a Connectable observable and call `connect()` manually.

```
const source$ = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4])
  .filter(x => x % 2)
  .map(x => x * x)
  .publish();

source$.subscribe(x => console.log(`Stream 1 ${x}`));
source$.subscribe(x => console.log(`Stream 2 ${x}`));

source$.connect();
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/waraqi/2/edit?js,console